# How to make the rotation of a 9 x 9 table?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to make the rotation in the following table from an angle of ninety degrees clockwise?

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
\draw[ultra thick] 
    (0,0)--(9,0)
    (0,1)--(9,1) 
    (0,2)--(9,2)
    (0,3)--(9,3)
    (0,4)--(9,4)
    (0,5)--(9,5)
    (0,6)--(9,6)
    (0,7)--(9,7)
    (0,8)--(9,8)
    (0,9)--(9,9);
\draw[ultra thick]
    (0,0)--(0,9)
    (1,0)--(1,9)
    (2,0)--(2,9)
    (3,0)--(3,9)
    (4,0)--(4,9)
    (5,0)--(5,9)
    (6,0)--(6,9)
    (7,0)--(7,9)
    (8,0)--(8,9)
    (9,0)--(9,9);

\node at (0.5,0.5) {6};
\node at (0.5,1.5) {3};
\node at (0.5,2.5) {0};
\node at (0.5,3.5) {6};
\node at (0.5,4.5) {3};
\node at (0.5,5.5) {0};
\node at (0.5,6.5) {6};
\node at (0.5,7.5) {3};
\node at (0.5,8.5) {0};
\node at (1.5,0.5) {7};
\node at (1.5,1.5) {4};
\node at (1.5,2.5) {1};
\node at (1.5,3.5) {7};
\node at (1.5,4.5) {4};
\node at (1.5,5.5) {1};
\node at (1.5,6.5) {7};
\node at (1.5,7.5) {4};
\node at (1.5,8.5) {1};
\node at (2.5,0.5) {8};
\node at (2.5,1.5) {5};
\node at (2.5,2.5) {2};
\node at (2.5,3.5) {8};
\node at (2.5,4.5) {5};
\node at (2.5,5.5) {2};
\node at (2.5,6.5) {8};
\node at (2.5,7.5) {5};
\node at (2.5,8.5) {2};
\node at (3.5,0.5) {0};
\node at (3.5,1.5) {6};
\node at (3.5,2.5) {3};
\node at (3.5,3.5) {0};
\node at (3.5,4.5) {6};
\node at (3.5,5.5) {3};
\node at (3.5,6.5) {0};
\node at (3.5,7.5) {6};
\node at (3.5,8.5) {3};
\node at (4.5,0.5) {1};
\node at (4.5,1.5) {7};
\node at (4.5,2.5) {4};
\node at (4.5,3.5) {1};
\node at (4.5,4.5) {7};
\node at (4.5,5.5) {4};
\node at (4.5,6.5) {1};
\node at (4.5,7.5) {7};
\node at (4.5,8.5) {4};
\node at (5.5,0.5) {2};
\node at (5.5,1.5) {8};
\node at (5.5,2.5) {5};
\node at (5.5,3.5) {2};
\node at (5.5,4.5) {8};
\node at (5.5,5.5) {5};
\node at (5.5,6.5) {2};
\node at (5.5,7.5) {8};
\node at (5.5,8.5) {5};
\node at (6.5,0.5) {3};
\node at (6.5,1.5) {0};
\node at (6.5,2.5) {6};
\node at (6.5,3.5) {3};
\node at (6.5,4.5) {0};
\node at (6.5,5.5) {6};
\node at (6.5,6.5) {3};
\node at (6.5,7.5) {0};
\node at (6.5,8.5) {6};
\node at (7.5,0.5) {4};
\node at (7.5,1.5) {1};
\node at (7.5,2.5) {7};
\node at (7.5,3.5) {4};
\node at (7.5,4.5) {1};
\node at (7.5,5.5) {7};
\node at (7.5,6.5) {4};
\node at (7.5,7.5) {1};
\node at (7.5,8.5) {7};
\node at (8.5,0.5) {5};
\node at (8.5,1.5) {2};
\node at (8.5,2.5) {8};
\node at (8.5,3.5) {5};
\node at (8.5,4.5) {2};
\node at (8.5,5.5) {8};
\node at (8.5,6.5) {5};
\node at (8.5,7.5) {2};
\node at (8.5,8.5) {8};

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you also want to rotate the texts (labels)?

Comment: `\end{center}` is missing. And puting an image of the result may help to understand your question ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use `\rotatebox{-90}{....}`

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \begin{document}
   \rotatebox{-90}{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
   \draw[ultra thick]
       (0,0)--(9,0)
       (0,1)--(9,1)
       (0,2)--(9,2)
       (0,3)--(9,3)
       (0,4)--(9,4)
       (0,5)--(9,5)
       (0,6)--(9,6)
       (0,7)--(9,7)
       (0,8)--(9,8)
       (0,9)--(9,9);
   \draw[ultra thick]
       (0,0)--(0,9)
       (1,0)--(1,9)
       (2,0)--(2,9)
       (3,0)--(3,9)
       (4,0)--(4,9)
       (5,0)--(5,9)
       (6,0)--(6,9)
       (7,0)--(7,9)
       (8,0)--(8,9)
       (9,0)--(9,9);

   \node at (0.5,0.5) {6};
   \node at (0.5,1.5) {3};
   \node at (0.5,2.5) {0};
   \node at (0.5,3.5) {6};
   \node at (0.5,4.5) {3};
   \node at (0.5,5.5) {0};
   \node at (0.5,6.5) {6};
   \node at (0.5,7.5) {3};
   \node at (0.5,8.5) {0};
   \node at (1.5,0.5) {7};
   \node at (1.5,1.5) {4};
   \node at (1.5,2.5) {1};
   \node at (1.5,3.5) {7};
   \node at (1.5,4.5) {4};
   \node at (1.5,5.5) {1};
   \node at (1.5,6.5) {7};
   \node at (1.5,7.5) {4};
   \node at (1.5,8.5) {1};
   \node at (2.5,0.5) {8};
   \node at (2.5,1.5) {5};
   \node at (2.5,2.5) {2};
   \node at (2.5,3.5) {8};
   \node at (2.5,4.5) {5};
   \node at (2.5,5.5) {2};
   \node at (2.5,6.5) {8};
   \node at (2.5,7.5) {5};
   \node at (2.5,8.5) {2};
   \node at (3.5,0.5) {0};
   \node at (3.5,1.5) {6};
   \node at (3.5,2.5) {3};
   \node at (3.5,3.5) {0};
   \node at (3.5,4.5) {6};
   \node at (3.5,5.5) {3};
   \node at (3.5,6.5) {0};
   \node at (3.5,7.5) {6};
   \node at (3.5,8.5) {3};
   \node at (4.5,0.5) {1};
   \node at (4.5,1.5) {7};
   \node at (4.5,2.5) {4};
   \node at (4.5,3.5) {1};
   \node at (4.5,4.5) {7};
   \node at (4.5,5.5) {4};
   \node at (4.5,6.5) {1};
   \node at (4.5,7.5) {7};
   \node at (4.5,8.5) {4};
   \node at (5.5,0.5) {2};
   \node at (5.5,1.5) {8};
   \node at (5.5,2.5) {5};
   \node at (5.5,3.5) {2};
   \node at (5.5,4.5) {8};
   \node at (5.5,5.5) {5};
   \node at (5.5,6.5) {2};
   \node at (5.5,7.5) {8};
   \node at (5.5,8.5) {5};
   \node at (6.5,0.5) {3};
   \node at (6.5,1.5) {0};
   \node at (6.5,2.5) {6};
   \node at (6.5,3.5) {3};
   \node at (6.5,4.5) {0};
   \node at (6.5,5.5) {6};
   \node at (6.5,6.5) {3};
   \node at (6.5,7.5) {0};
   \node at (6.5,8.5) {6};
   \node at (7.5,0.5) {4};
   \node at (7.5,1.5) {1};
   \node at (7.5,2.5) {7};
   \node at (7.5,3.5) {4};
   \node at (7.5,4.5) {1};
   \node at (7.5,5.5) {7};
   \node at (7.5,6.5) {4};
   \node at (7.5,7.5) {1};
   \node at (7.5,8.5) {7};
   \node at (8.5,0.5) {5};
   \node at (8.5,1.5) {2};
   \node at (8.5,2.5) {8};
   \node at (8.5,3.5) {5};
   \node at (8.5,4.5) {2};
   \node at (8.5,5.5) {8};
   \node at (8.5,6.5) {5};
   \node at (8.5,7.5) {2};
   \node at (8.5,8.5) {8};

   \end{tikzpicture}%
   }
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Use package `rotating` and `\begin{turn}{-90}...\end{turn}`

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage{tikz,rotating}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{turn}{-90}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
   \draw[ultra thick]
       (0,0)--(9,0)
       (0,1)--(9,1)
       (0,2)--(9,2)
       (0,3)--(9,3)
       (0,4)--(9,4)
       (0,5)--(9,5)
       (0,6)--(9,6)
       (0,7)--(9,7)
       (0,8)--(9,8)
       (0,9)--(9,9);
   \draw[ultra thick]
       (0,0)--(0,9)
       (1,0)--(1,9)
       (2,0)--(2,9)
       (3,0)--(3,9)
       (4,0)--(4,9)
       (5,0)--(5,9)
       (6,0)--(6,9)
       (7,0)--(7,9)
       (8,0)--(8,9)
       (9,0)--(9,9);

   \node at (0.5,0.5) {6};
   \node at (0.5,1.5) {3};
   \node at (0.5,2.5) {0};
   \node at (0.5,3.5) {6};
   \node at (0.5,4.5) {3};
   \node at (0.5,5.5) {0};
   \node at (0.5,6.5) {6};
   \node at (0.5,7.5) {3};
   \node at (0.5,8.5) {0};
   \node at (1.5,0.5) {7};
   \node at (1.5,1.5) {4};
   \node at (1.5,2.5) {1};
   \node at (1.5,3.5) {7};
   \node at (1.5,4.5) {4};
   \node at (1.5,5.5) {1};
   \node at (1.5,6.5) {7};
   \node at (1.5,7.5) {4};
   \node at (1.5,8.5) {1};
   \node at (2.5,0.5) {8};
   \node at (2.5,1.5) {5};
   \node at (2.5,2.5) {2};
   \node at (2.5,3.5) {8};
   \node at (2.5,4.5) {5};
   \node at (2.5,5.5) {2};
   \node at (2.5,6.5) {8};
   \node at (2.5,7.5) {5};
   \node at (2.5,8.5) {2};
   \node at (3.5,0.5) {0};
   \node at (3.5,1.5) {6};
   \node at (3.5,2.5) {3};
   \node at (3.5,3.5) {0};
   \node at (3.5,4.5) {6};
   \node at (3.5,5.5) {3};
   \node at (3.5,6.5) {0};
   \node at (3.5,7.5) {6};
   \node at (3.5,8.5) {3};
   \node at (4.5,0.5) {1};
   \node at (4.5,1.5) {7};
   \node at (4.5,2.5) {4};
   \node at (4.5,3.5) {1};
   \node at (4.5,4.5) {7};
   \node at (4.5,5.5) {4};
   \node at (4.5,6.5) {1};
   \node at (4.5,7.5) {7};
   \node at (4.5,8.5) {4};
   \node at (5.5,0.5) {2};
   \node at (5.5,1.5) {8};
   \node at (5.5,2.5) {5};
   \node at (5.5,3.5) {2};
   \node at (5.5,4.5) {8};
   \node at (5.5,5.5) {5};
   \node at (5.5,6.5) {2};
   \node at (5.5,7.5) {8};
   \node at (5.5,8.5) {5};
   \node at (6.5,0.5) {3};
   \node at (6.5,1.5) {0};
   \node at (6.5,2.5) {6};
   \node at (6.5,3.5) {3};
   \node at (6.5,4.5) {0};
   \node at (6.5,5.5) {6};
   \node at (6.5,6.5) {3};
   \node at (6.5,7.5) {0};
   \node at (6.5,8.5) {6};
   \node at (7.5,0.5) {4};
   \node at (7.5,1.5) {1};
   \node at (7.5,2.5) {7};
   \node at (7.5,3.5) {4};
   \node at (7.5,4.5) {1};
   \node at (7.5,5.5) {7};
   \node at (7.5,6.5) {4};
   \node at (7.5,7.5) {1};
   \node at (7.5,8.5) {7};
   \node at (8.5,0.5) {5};
   \node at (8.5,1.5) {2};
   \node at (8.5,2.5) {8};
   \node at (8.5,3.5) {5};
   \node at (8.5,4.5) {2};
   \node at (8.5,5.5) {8};
   \node at (8.5,6.5) {5};
   \node at (8.5,7.5) {2};
   \node at (8.5,8.5) {8};

   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{turn}
   \end{document}
   ```

The result is the same:

[image]

Instead, if you intended to rotate the number combinations, but not the number shapes, add `rotate=-90` in the `tikzpicture` options:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4,rotate=-90]
\draw[ultra thick]
    (0,0)--(9,0)
    (0,1)--(9,1)
    (0,2)--(9,2)
    (0,3)--(9,3)
    (0,4)--(9,4)
    (0,5)--(9,5)
    (0,6)--(9,6)
    (0,7)--(9,7)
    (0,8)--(9,8)
    (0,9)--(9,9);
\draw[ultra thick]
    (0,0)--(0,9)
    (1,0)--(1,9)
    (2,0)--(2,9)
    (3,0)--(3,9)
    (4,0)--(4,9)
    (5,0)--(5,9)
    (6,0)--(6,9)
    (7,0)--(7,9)
    (8,0)--(8,9)
    (9,0)--(9,9);

\node at (0.5,0.5) {6};
\node at (0.5,1.5) {3};
\node at (0.5,2.5) {0};
\node at (0.5,3.5) {6};
\node at (0.5,4.5) {3};
\node at (0.5,5.5) {0};
\node at (0.5,6.5) {6};
\node at (0.5,7.5) {3};
\node at (0.5,8.5) {0};
\node at (1.5,0.5) {7};
\node at (1.5,1.5) {4};
\node at (1.5,2.5) {1};
\node at (1.5,3.5) {7};
\node at (1.5,4.5) {4};
\node at (1.5,5.5) {1};
\node at (1.5,6.5) {7};
\node at (1.5,7.5) {4};
\node at (1.5,8.5) {1};
\node at (2.5,0.5) {8};
\node at (2.5,1.5) {5};
\node at (2.5,2.5) {2};
\node at (2.5,3.5) {8};
\node at (2.5,4.5) {5};
\node at (2.5,5.5) {2};
\node at (2.5,6.5) {8};
\node at (2.5,7.5) {5};
\node at (2.5,8.5) {2};
\node at (3.5,0.5) {0};
\node at (3.5,1.5) {6};
\node at (3.5,2.5) {3};
\node at (3.5,3.5) {0};
\node at (3.5,4.5) {6};
\node at (3.5,5.5) {3};
\node at (3.5,6.5) {0};
\node at (3.5,7.5) {6};
\node at (3.5,8.5) {3};
\node at (4.5,0.5) {1};
\node at (4.5,1.5) {7};
\node at (4.5,2.5) {4};
\node at (4.5,3.5) {1};
\node at (4.5,4.5) {7};
\node at (4.5,5.5) {4};
\node at (4.5,6.5) {1};
\node at (4.5,7.5) {7};
\node at (4.5,8.5) {4};
\node at (5.5,0.5) {2};
\node at (5.5,1.5) {8};
\node at (5.5,2.5) {5};
\node at (5.5,3.5) {2};
\node at (5.5,4.5) {8};
\node at (5.5,5.5) {5};
\node at (5.5,6.5) {2};
\node at (5.5,7.5) {8};
\node at (5.5,8.5) {5};
\node at (6.5,0.5) {3};
\node at (6.5,1.5) {0};
\node at (6.5,2.5) {6};
\node at (6.5,3.5) {3};
\node at (6.5,4.5) {0};
\node at (6.5,5.5) {6};
\node at (6.5,6.5) {3};
\node at (6.5,7.5) {0};
\node at (6.5,8.5) {6};
\node at (7.5,0.5) {4};
\node at (7.5,1.5) {1};
\node at (7.5,2.5) {7};
\node at (7.5,3.5) {4};
\node at (7.5,4.5) {1};
\node at (7.5,5.5) {7};
\node at (7.5,6.5) {4};
\node at (7.5,7.5) {1};
\node at (7.5,8.5) {7};
\node at (8.5,0.5) {5};
\node at (8.5,1.5) {2};
\node at (8.5,2.5) {8};
\node at (8.5,3.5) {5};
\node at (8.5,4.5) {2};
\node at (8.5,5.5) {8};
\node at (8.5,6.5) {5};
\node at (8.5,7.5) {2};
\node at (8.5,8.5) {8};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is one double `foreach` with some use of `mod` function in a `grid`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,scale=.4]
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,0) grid (9,9);
    \foreach \i in {0,...,8}
      \foreach \j in {0,...,8}
        \path let \n1={int(mod((3*mod(11-\i,3)+\j,9))} in (.5+\i,8.5-\j) node{\n1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]